# Does class B that implements interface I that extends interface J also extends type I?

Tags: java, class, dictionary, interface, implementation

The code getting me confusing:

```
 Collection<? extends Map<String, String>> a = 
                       new ArrayList<SortedMap<String, String>>();
 SortedMap<String, String> b = new TreeMap<String, String>();
 b.put("1","a");
```

Error:

```
 a.add(b);
```

The method add(capture#2-of ? extends Map) in the type Collection> is not applicable for the arguments (SortedMap)
Why? SortedMap extends Map and TreeMap is a class that implements SortedMap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This means

```
 Collection<? extends Map<String, String>> a ;
```

The elements of `a` are an **unknown** class which extends a Map.  You means when you get a value out it is a Map, but you cannot say which map would be valid to add to the collection.

For example, `a` doesn't know the class which extends Map so it cannot allow any sub-class as it cannot know which is valid.

```
List<HashMap<String, String>> listOfMap = new ArrayList<>();
Collection<? extends Map<String, String>> a = listOfMap;
SortedMap<String, String> b = new TreeMap<String, String>();
b.put("1", "a");
a.add(b); // produces an error  as it should.
```

If you change `a` to be

```
Collection<SortedMap<String, String>> a = new ArrayList<SortedMap<String, String>>();
```

It is fine to add `b` as it is this type.

Comment: Why I cannot say? Each type that extends Map will be valid.

Comment: @user710818 That is not what `? extends` means.  It *doesn't* mean any sub-class is valid, it means the sub-class is unknown.  See my example.

Comment: understand. Thanks a lot!